# Port vulnerability scanner not catching http banner

Tags: python, http, security, port-scanning

Hi all this is my first ever stack overflow question so please bare with me!

I've written a pretty basic vulnerability scanner which scans a range of ports on a specified IP address, pulls the banner info, adds it to a string then uses googlesearch to find links to potential exploits and vulnerabilities related to the banner info for all open port (Or at least this is what I'd like it to do).

The script executes and returns ftp and ssh banners but **it doesn't return any http banners when I've tested it against some targets which I know have open http on 80 and 8080**. I'm not sure why. I have a feeling it's something in my banner grabbing function. Any help would be great.

Here's the code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket
import os
import sys
import colorama
from colorama import Fore

def retBanner(ip,port):
    try:
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)
        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect((ip,port))
        banner = s.recv(1024)
        return banner.decode()
    except:
        return

def checkVulns(banner):
    try :
        from googlesearch import search
    except ImportError:
        print (Fore.RED + 'No module named google')

    query = banner

    for x in search(query, tld="com", num=10, stop=10, pause=2):
            print (Fore.GREEN + ('[*] Link to potential exploit: ' + x ))

def main():
        portlist = range(1,500) # <-------- CHANGE THIS FOR PORT LIST RANGE
        ip = "..." # <-------------- CHANGE THIS
        for port in portlist:
                banner = retBanner(ip, port)
                if banner:
                        print (Fore.YELLOW + ("[*]"  + str(ip) + "/" + str(port) + ": " + str(banner)))
                        checkVulns(banner)
main()
```

Comment: Please upload the code :)

Comment: Just added. First ever post so getting used to it =)

Comment: Well, I'm not a python expert and It may not help you (was looking for other tags). I added the python tag, but the first thing I would do is to see if you are getting any exception info from the `retBanner ` function. Now you are not printing there any info - and it may be relevant to know if any exception actually occurs.

Comment: Ok I'll take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Http server will return nothing until you send request. There is no such thing as a banner

Comment: @NobbyNobbs Ah of course, I need to request the response header  doh! Thanks.